# get database records from ajax (error 500)

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-blade

I am doing an AJAX request by GET to receive data from the database in view.

My HTML:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('myaccount.facturacion.guardar') }}">
@csrf

...

<div class="col-lg-3">
        <div class="form-group mb-3">
            <label>Código postal</label>
            <input type="text" name="codigo_postal" class="form-control" id="codigo_postal" maxlength="5" required>
        </div>
    </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <div class="form-group mb-3">
                <label>Localidad</label>
                <input type="text" name="localidad" id="localidad" class="form-control" required>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <div class="form-group mb-3">
                <label>Provincia</label>
                <input type="text" name="provincia" id="provincia" class="form-control" required>
            </div>
        </div>

</form>
```

The AJAX request I'm trying to do: Note: i replaced the original url with: ...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var codigo_postal = $('#codigo_postal');
    codigo_postal.keyup(function () {
        var value = codigo_postal.val();
        if (value.length == 5) {

            $.ajax({
                url: '.../postal/' + value,
                method:'GET'
            }).done(function(res){
                alert(res)
            });
        }
    })
});
```

The route to which I am trying to make the request:

```
Route::get('postal/{codigo_postal}', 'MyAccountController@obtenerCodigoPostal')->name('postal_code.get');
```

The controller method that is attached to the route:

```
public function obtenerCodigoPostal($codigo_postal) {
        $cp = Categoria::where('codigo_postal', $codigo_postal)->first();
        $postal_code = $cp->codigo_postal;
        return response(['postal_code' => $postal_code]);
    }
```

The error I am getting:

[image]

Can u help me? pls

Comment: A 500 error means there's an issue with your server side logic. I'd suggest starting your debugging there.

Comment: However, the 'error' image shows that the response is a 302, which is a successful status code...? Also there is no `#codigo_postal` element in the HTML you've shown.

Comment: check the edit! @RoryMcCrossan. I failed to copy the input and the put image

Comment: probably in your query "->get()" is missing before "->first()"

Comment: You can check server-side errors in `storage/logs/laravel.log`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the response is getting back to the server successfully, but as Rory said, it is an error on the server side code.  Here:

```
public function obtenerCodigoPostal($codigo_postal) {
    $cp = Categoria::where('codigo_postal', $codigo_postal)->first();
    $postal_code = $cp->codigo_postal;
    return response(['postal_code' => $postal_code]);
}
```

If you are trying to return whether a `Categoria` exists, this is a little different.  Right now, you are returning exactly the same thing that comes into the method, the `codigo_postal`.  But, if a `Categoria` with that postal code does not exist, it will fail (500 error) on the server as the `$cp` is **null** and thus cannot pull the postal code from a null object.

I suggest trying to send either a postal code back, or a fail message, along with an error check in the middle to prevent the server error:

```
public function obtenerCodigoPostal($codigo_postal) {
    $cp = Categoria::where('codigo_postal', $codigo_postal)->first();
    if($cp === null){
        return response('Fail', 200);
    }
    else{
        $postal_code = $cp->codigo_postal;
        return response('Pass', 200);
    }
}
```

You can tweak the response later - this will just give you a way to test out success.

HTH